# ArangoDB weight in traverse that's not shortest_path

Tags: arangodb

Is it possible to have something like a Weight in a traversal?

```
FOR v,e,p
IN 1..4
ANY "entities/foo" 
GRAPH "friendGraph"
OPTIONS {
bfs: true,
uniqueVertices: 'global',
weight: 'friendType'
}
FILTER v._id == "entities/bar"
RETURN p
```

I have one data collection (entities) and one edge collection (edges).

Entities has friendType, which is an INT between 1 and 5. It would be amazing if the query could use friendType as a weight.

If that won't work, if I broke out entities into 5 different collections and somehow put a different weight on each collection?

**If none of those works, any other suggestions would be valued.**

I do realize there is a weight feature in shortestPath. However, I need to find all the paths, not just the shortest.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the expected behavior of a weight feature in normal traversal? In the shortest path calculation, it is used to favor one edge over another at each "junction" with multiple path options if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: That's the problem. There is no weight in a normal traversal. I'm hoping there is a way to create a query that will work as if there's a weight just like in shortest_path.

Comment: I'm aware that there's no weight option for normal traversal, but the question is what you expect it to do from a technical point of view as well as in terms of the result. Is it supposed to discard certain paths from the result set based on the weight? Or favor following one edge over another if there are multiple to choose from? Let's say there are 4 outgoing edges, would you want the traversal to follow only one edge (the one with the highest weight value)?

Comment: I see. the expected result would be to prefer the highest weight. It would not discard the lower weight paths. It would just start with greater weights when possible. Thank you!

Comment: I see. It's possible to aggregate edge weights in a post-traversal step, summing all weight values on the path and sort by it. If edges were sorted by a weight attribute in the linked lists of the edge index, that would probably be more efficient, because the ones with the highest height would be at the top. Changing these weight values a lot would invalidate the index heavily however, so not sure if it's a good idea. Feel free to open a feature request on https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues anyway.

Comment: Thank you. Are there any examples on how to sum weights in the path and sort?

Comment: Have a look here: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/arangodb/GZ6jG_6OWC4/discussion There is no SORT node, but you can simply add it after COLLECT and before RETURN.